# jQuery filter searching a table cell only works for some items but not all

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a way to highlight table rows based on what a person types into a searchbox. It seems to only work if I type the whole text of the table cell into the search box, not if I type only part of it. Here's my example table row:

```
<tr class="all rate" style="display: table-row;">
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">ABB</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">ABC Boulder </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align:center;">US Dollar</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">PKSE</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">COMPANY LOCAL</td>
</tr>

//jquery code
$('td').each(function(i,td){
  $(td).filter(function(){return $(this).text().toLowerCase() == s;}).closest('tr').css('background-color','#ff0000');
}));
```

That's not the exact code, but my copy & paste wasn't working. If I do a search for "ABB", it will highlight the row with the provided color. But, if I search for "COM" (of company), nothing gets highlighted.

If I search for "COMPANY LOCAL" then it works. So it looks like the search isn't doing a partial search. How do I get it to work with a partial search?

Comment: $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf("com")

Comment: DUH!!! I knew that == was the problem. Please answer in the answer area so i can accept your response and give you credit!

Comment: You need to do a "contains" search rather than an "equals" search, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript

Comment: by the way... i was mistaken... it doesn't work. for some reason, no matter what i type in the box, everything get's returned as a match no matter what goes in the box :(

Answer (score 1):

I updated the code to use the case in-sensitive search for `:contains` selector rather than using `.each` with `indexOf` see this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/) for full details.

The main reason is that you are using `.each` and if a td which has a match is the first td and the rest of the `tds` do not have a matching character or word that is typed in the input box it will hide it back.

---

Maybe this helps you out using the `indexOf` the given text in the tds

```js
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
  return function(elem) {
    return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };
});
$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function() {
  let val = $(this).val();
  $('tr>td:not(:contains(' + val + '))').closest('tr').css('display', 'none');
  $('tr>td:contains(' + val + ')').closest('tr').css('display', 'block');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search">
<table>
  <tr class="all rate" style="display: table-row;">
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">ABB</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">ABC Boulder </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align:center;">US Dollar</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">PKSE</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">COMPANY LOCAL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="all rate" style="display: table-row;">
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">ABB</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">ABC Boulder </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align:center;">US Dollar</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">PKSE</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">COMPANY LOCAL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="all rate" style="display: table-row;">
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">ABB</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">ABC Boulder </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align:center;">US Dollar</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">PKSE</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">COMPANY LOCAL</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="all rate" style="display: table-row;">
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">ABB</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">ABC Boulder </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align:center;">US Dollar</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">PKSE</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"> pakistan</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hmm... coming across another problem cause as i type, i'm making the td's disappear and now it's not searching the whole td's

Comment: what do you mean by not searching the whole `tds` ? i couldnt get what you mean, can you show the js code for the field you have along with the `table` inside which the `tds` are residing

Comment: Sorry for the vague comment. I'm trying to hide the rows and only show as i type but it's not working. My rows aren't hiding. I'll edit the question using the revised code

Comment: i updated my code snippet see if this is how you are trying to hide the rows @Damien

Comment: I think i know what the problem is... even using your code, the same thing. no matter what i type at this point, using the highlight for testing purposes, everything gets highlighted red. anything i type comes back as a match... 0_o

Comment: i updated the example it shows / hides now, rather than turning background to red are you seeing the latest code?

Comment: same issue... everything disappears... only to reappear when i delete the text from the search box.

Comment: yeah you are right , i just used different approach see the answer @Damien

Comment: i figured it out. updated my code up there. check it... my only question is, how can i shorten my code? Broke it down by getting rid of all the chaining

Comment: i already changed the code for you if you see the latest code it uses contains overridden as case insensitive it would be a better approach and efficient

Comment: very cool. thanks! although, if you do know how to shorten the code i put up there, I'd like to know, for informational purposes, how it's done :)